# How to make Django upload destination folder configurable through GUI run-time

Tags: python, django

I will be uploading files using a cron job on a server. If my server gets full, I will add another hard disk to add the new files there. I am building a metadata file for these uploaded files. At any point of time I would like to be able to download these files from the model form using MEDIA_URL.

At such a point of time the MEDIA_ROOT needs to be able to access both the paths if the 2 disks are added. How could this be resolved? I am aware of the urls where dynamic folders can be created to add the files at run time but not change the MEDIA_ROOT.

Is there any alternate solution? Using django 1.6.5, I have referred to the following urls:

[Changing Django settings at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528723/changing-django-settings-at-runtime)

[how to access media root in py file](http://goobbe.com/questions/485961/how-to-access-media-root-in-py-file)

Comment: Write your own file storage backend, don't try to hack like this as how globals work depend on your web server process/thread model.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thank you for your response, can you please elaborate. I am working on linux  where the destination folder can be configured using GUI for storing the uploaded files

Comment: Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-file-storage/ - it's a complex topic so you need to split it to smaller subproblems