# Dynamic settings.py

Tags: python, django

I have used [django-constance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-constance) as a library.
Although one thing I notice is that when I tried using `ADMIN` and `MANAGER`

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
'ADMINS': ([('Errors', 'admin@gmail.com')], 'Admin Emails'),
}
```

sending of emails is not working.

In MANAGER I have tried this:

```
MANAGER = CONSTANCE_CONFIG['ADMINS'][0]
```

still sending emails is not working. Am I missing a wrong implementation?
Or can you suggest any other library which can override `ADMIN` and `MANAGER` in `settings.py`. I am using Django 1.8.5 and Python 3.

also when trying to import inside settings.py it produces error as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "sending of emails is not working"? Any errors? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to change django settings dynamically?  Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528723/changing-django-settings-at-runtime?

Comment: @alecxe, I used Admin and Manager for sending error log in my email, when not using django-constance it is sending errors in the emails(Which is the right way) But when I used the way of django-constance, no errors but It doesn't send my emails.

Comment: @PeterBrittain Yes I tried a couple of them here as well https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/live-setting/, But cant seem to find a way to make the Admin and Manager work for them.

Comment: Did you also see the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6528794/4994021) that says you must not change the settings?  Yes there are some you can change (as noted in the comments to the answer), but it is not documented or supported...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1#`  Probably you already know, `django-constance` does not support tuple. Basically it is really hard to detect a widget for tuple specially
in your case. ADMINS can be `added/deleted` so how possibly you can make it dynamic through a `single widget`..!!(think about all django widgets). So here
 `CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS` will also not work.

`2#` I think you are misunderstanding the working of django constance.
It does not refresh your `django server`. So `MANAGER = CONSTANCE_CONFIG['ADMINS'][0]` is totally wrong(even using `CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS`). You accessing `constant` value here(not dynamic).
 You need to access it like

```
from constance import config
print(config.ADMINS)
```

`3#` Default logging config uses `AdminEmailHandler` class for `mail_admins`, which uses `ADMINS` value from `django settings`, not `constance config`.

So one possible solution might be to create your own `handler` class which will use `ADMINS` value from `constance config`. So change your `setting.py` to

```
CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    'ADMIN1': ('admin@gmail.com', 'This one will receive error on 500'),
} # you can add as many admins as you want with ADMIN1, ADMIN2 etc(no tuple)
```

then create your own handler class which will use `CONSTANCE_CONFIG`.

```
from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
from constance import config
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMultiAlternatives


class ConstanceEmailHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    def send_mail(self, subject, message, html_message=None, fail_silently=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # create a list of ADMIN emails here, if you have more then one ADMIN
        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives('%s%s' % (settings.EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX, subject),
                                  message, settings.SERVER_EMAIL, [config.ADMIN1],
                                  connection=self.connection())
        if html_message:
            mail.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
        mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
```

And then change your `LOGGER` config. I would recommend you to copy default logger config from `django.utils.log`(DEFAULT_LOGGING) if you  do not have your custom `LOGGING` setup. And change `mail_admins` to

```
'mail_admins': {
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'filters': ['require_debug_false'], # change it to require_debug_true if you want to test it locally.
    'class': '<yourproject>.<yourfile>.ConstanceEmailHandler', # path to newly created handler class
    'include_html': True
    },
```

Comment: What if you want to have multiple admins like:
(
    ('admin1', 'admin1@domain'),
    ('admin1', 'admin2@domain.tld'),
)

How will you be able to use it in constance as well as the function you implement?

Comment: Please read the Answer carefully. Add ADMIN2 = (<email>, <helptext>) in ```constance config```. And then ```[config.ADMIN1, config.ADMIN2]``` in ```send_mail``` function