# Prevent any CRUD functionality on a django model

Tags: django, django-models, crud

Hello Im currently using a third party package called `django-river` to implement a sort of workflow system into my application. The reason for using this is because it allows the user to dynamically generate workflows and attatch functions on the fly . Im currently using this across some of my models that require this  functionality. However , there is one model that i wish to restrict this freedom. I do not wish to allow the user to add any instances than the one i have added from the start , or edit them.

Hence my question is:

1. Is there a way to achieve this locking mechanism of the django models?

Comment: revoke `change/delete` permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage [DB-level permissions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-grant.html) (google how to implement it for your database). And in django side add [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/)
with different users, for e.g.:

**A** user - can only read your spesific table, in default settings;

**B** user - has full permissions.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'A',
        'PASSWORD': 'qwerty'
    },
    'full': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'B',
        'PASSWORD': 'qwerty'
    }
}
```

```py
MyModel.objects.using('full').create(...)

MyModel.objects.create(...)  # OperationError
```

Or you can [change user at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528723/changing-django-settings-at-runtime).